# SQL Developer Create Function to find statistical normalization

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, stored-functions

I am trying to create a function that calculates statistical normalized values of a table of numbers. I keep getting the error ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero. HELP!!!

```
CREATE FUNCTION NORMALIZATION (OriginalValues NUMBER, MaxNumber NUMBER, MinNumber NUMBER)

RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (OriginalValues - MinNumber)/(MaxNumber - MinNumber);
END NORMALIZATION;
/

CREATE TABLE X  (
    AGE    NUMBER(5)   CONSTRAINT AgePK PRIMARY KEY
    );

INSERT INTO X     VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (32);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (25);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (102);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (109);
INSERT INTO X     VALUES (111);

SELECT Age, NORMALIZATION(Age, MAX(Age), MIN(Age)) AS NormalizedAge
FROM X
GROUP BY Age;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you test your select with `min` and `max` values

```
SELECT Age, MAX(Age), MIN(Age)
FROM X
group by age;
```

you will get

```
Age Min max
1   1   1
3   3   3
5   5   5
25  25  25
32  32  32
102 102 102
109 109 109
111 111 111
```

So the result of the function should not be surprising

```
  (OriginalValues - MinNumber)/(MaxNumber - MinNumber)
  (1 - 1) / (1 - 1) -- for the first Row
  (2 - 2) / (2 - 2) -- for the second Row
```

and so on

you can use analytic function to get the min and the max value

```
SELECT Age
     , min(age) over () as min_val
     , max(age) over () as max_val
FROM X
group by age;
```

the result

```
Age min max
1   1   111
3   1   111
5   1   111
25  1   111
32  1   111
102 1   111
109 1   111
111 1   111
```

you select coul look like

```
select age,
       NORMALIZATION(age,max_val,min_val)
 from ( SELECT Age
             , min(age) over () as min_val
             , max(age) over () as max_val
        FROM X
        group by age
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split this up and see where the problem is.
The division by 0 is most likely due to Min(age) being the same as max(age)

I think the problem is in your SELECT

I cant throubleshoot atm, but could you try running it like:

```
SELECT age
     , NORMALISATION(age, (SELECT MAX(age) FROM X), (SELECT MIN(age) FROM X)) as normalisedAge
  FROM X
```